# Where can I buy Glico Curry online in the United States?

Tags: shopping, curry, japanese-cuisine

My wife and I brought back a box of Glico Medium Curry that we purchased on our trip to Canada this past year.  I think we bought it at the Daiso store in Vancouver.  After trying it for the first time just recently, we both fell in love with it and now can't imagine not having it occasionally.   Unfortunately, I can't find anywhere to purchase it, either locally, or online.  There are many other brands of Japanese Curry that are available online, but I'm afraid they might not taste the same as the one we had from Glico.  Is there somewhere where I can buy this product online, or would any of the other brands that I could get locally be any bit similar?  (Such as Vermont Curry, or S&B Golden Curry?)  I live in Arkansas.

Thank you!

Comment: Meta on closing:  http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1292/what-types-of-sourcing-questions-should-be-allowed-revisit-march-2013-plea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, this is hard to find. I know I've seen it in some asian grocery stores, but none of the online groceries that I could find seem to list it, even the venerable [H-Mart](http://www.hmart.com/). No Amazon sellers (usually a good source for odd groceries) right now, either.

Fortunately I found one source for you, [eBay seller "hirokojapan"](http://www.ebay.com/sch/hirokojapan/m.html?_ipg=&_sac=1&_trksid=p3911.c0.m1538) has a persistent [listing for Glico Curry Sauce](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Japan-japanese-curry-hot-sweet-hayashi-rice-stew-roux-sauce-Glico-House-/140711154437?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&var=&hash=item6674d6c178), $5.99 each, $3.95 shipping to the US from Osaka, JP. You select the flavor you want, from Curry, Curry Sweet, Curry Hot, Stew or Rice.

The individual listing link will expire eventually, but future readers can look up the seller directly and see if they are listing a similar item (or message them with a request).

Comment: Thank you!  These are quite expensive.  I've purchased some alternate brands locally from an Asian grocery, and I will try them first to see if they are similar to the Glico.  If they are close enough, I won't bother with the added cost, but if they aren't I guess I'll just have to spend the extra money.

Answer (score 1):

While not exactly the same, S&B Brand Golden Curry is a very similar product, and one that, in my experience, is more common in America. Even if it's not 100% identical, it will be very very nearly so — the rich, thick, stew-y style of Japanese curry.

Also, I know that your question was about where to *buy* Glico curry, but it can also be easily made from scratch, and with ingredients that are often easier to find than the pre-made curry roux bricks. http://www.seriouseats.com/recipes/2010/06/how-to-make-japanese-curry-rice-from-scratch-recipe.html is a good recipe that I have used before.

Comment: I did end up trying the Vermont Curry, and it tasted close enough to the Glico Curry to be an acceptable substitute.  I see no need in spending the extra money to import something when the Vermont Curry is good enough.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Vermont curry tasted very similar to Glico, I definitely recommend you try it first before you try splurging on internationally shipped Glico or anything like that.